# How can I dynamically generate the preformatted text for a selected html element and display both the preformatted text and the normal text below it?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that dynamically generates preformatted text for a selected html element. I want to display both preformatted text and normal text.

I wrote a script like this, but for example, the tag with the class name "code above 2" converts itself and the tag above it to preformatted text. I want to show the preformatted and normal texts of these two tags as a whole, not separately.

```js
// Function to convert specified elements to preformatted text
function convertToPreformattedText() {
  var codeElements = document.querySelectorAll('.code');

  // Iterate over each code element
  codeElements.forEach(function(element) {
    var classNames = Array.from(element.classList);
    var num = getClassNumber(classNames);

    if (classNames.includes('above')) {
      // Convert elements above the current element
      if (num > 0) {
        var targetElements = findTargetElementsAbove(element, num - 1);
        targetElements.push(element);
        targetElements.forEach(function(targetElement) {
          convertElementToPreformattedText(targetElement);
        });
      } else if (num < 0) {
        // Convert elements below the current element (absolute value of num)
        var targetElements = findTargetElementsBelow(element, Math.abs(num) - 1);
        targetElements.push(element);
        targetElements.forEach(function(targetElement) {
          convertElementToPreformattedText(targetElement);
        });
      } else {
        // Convert only the current element
        convertElementToPreformattedText(element);
      }
    } else if (classNames.includes('below')) {
      // Convert elements below the current element
      if (num > 0) {
        var targetElements = findTargetElementsBelow(element, num - 1);
        targetElements.push(element);
        targetElements.forEach(function(targetElement) {
          convertElementToPreformattedText(targetElement);
        });
      } else if (num < 0) {
        // Convert elements above the current element (absolute value of num)
        var targetElements = findTargetElementsAbove(element, Math.abs(num) - 1);
        targetElements.push(element);
        targetElements.forEach(function(targetElement) {
          convertElementToPreformattedText(targetElement);
        });
      } else {
        // Convert only the current element
        convertElementToPreformattedText(element);
      }
    }
  });
}

// Function to extract the numeric class value
function getClassNumber(classNames) {
  var num = 0;
  classNames.forEach(function(className) {
    if (!isNaN(parseInt(className))) {
      num = parseInt(className);
    }
  });
  return num;
}

// Function to find target elements above the given element
function findTargetElementsAbove(element, num) {
  var targetElements = [];
  var siblingCount = 0;
  while (element.previousElementSibling && siblingCount < num) {
    element = element.previousElementSibling;
    targetElements.push(element);
    siblingCount++;
  }
  return targetElements.reverse();
}

// Function to find target elements below the given element
function findTargetElementsBelow(element, num) {
  var targetElements = [];
  var siblingCount = 0;
  while (element.nextElementSibling && siblingCount < num) {
    element = element.nextElementSibling;
    targetElements.push(element);
    siblingCount++;
  }
  return targetElements;
}

// Function to convert the given element to preformatted text
function convertElementToPreformattedText(element) {
  var tagName = element.tagName.toLowerCase();
  var preformattedText = document.createElement('pre');
  var originalContent = document.createElement('div');
  originalContent.className = 'original-content';
  originalContent.innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
  preformattedText.textContent = "<" + tagName + ">" + element.innerHTML + "</" + tagName + ">";
  preformattedText.appendChild(originalContent);

  var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.className = 'content-wrapper';
  wrapper.appendChild(preformattedText);
  wrapper.appendChild(originalContent);

  element.parentNode.replaceChild(wrapper, element);
}


// Convert elements to preformatted text when the DOM is loaded
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  convertToPreformattedText();
});
```

For the html code below:

```
<h4>Code Above Example</h4>
<p class="code above">An example paragraph.</p>

<p>An example paragraph. 1</p>
<p class="code above 2">An example paragraph. 2</p>

<p>An example paragraph. 1</p>
<p>An example paragraph. 2</p>
<p class="code above 3">An example paragraph. 3</p>

<p class="code above -2">An example paragraph. 1</p>
<p>An example paragraph. 2</p>

<h4>Code Below Example</h4>
<p class="code below">An example paragraph.</p>

<p class="code below 2">An example paragraph. 1</p>
<p>An example paragraph. 2</p>

<p class="code below 3">An example paragraph. 1</p>
<p>An example paragraph. 2</p>
<p>An example paragraph. 3</p>

<p>An example paragraph. 1</p>
<p class="code below -2">An example paragraph. 2</p>
```

This is how it should be displayed on the web page.

```
Code Above Example
<p>An example paragraph.</p>
An example paragraph.

<p>An example paragraph. 1</p>
<p>An example paragraph. 2</p>
An example paragraph. 1 
An example paragraph. 2

<p>An example paragraph. 1</p>
<p>An example paragraph. 2</p>
<p>An example paragraph. 3</p>
An example paragraph. 1 
An example paragraph. 2
An example paragraph. 3

<p>An example paragraph. 1</p>
<p>An example paragraph. 2</p>
An example paragraph. 1 
An example paragraph. 2

Code Below Example
<p>An example paragraph.</p>
An example paragraph.

<p>An example paragraph. 1</p>
<p>An example paragraph. 2</p>
An example paragraph. 1 
An example paragraph. 2

<p>An example paragraph. 1</p>
<p>An example paragraph. 2</p>
<p>An example paragraph. 3</p>
An example paragraph. 1 
An example paragraph. 2
An example paragraph. 3

<p>An example paragraph. 1</p>
<p>An example paragraph. 2</p>
An example paragraph. 1 
An example paragraph. 2
```